# DirectX tag synonyms inconsistency

Tags: discussion, tags

While browsing the main [tag synonyms](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) list, I bumped into something quite odd: [directx](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx), [directx9](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx9), [directx10](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx10), and [directx11](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx11) are *target* tags, and tags such as [direct3d10](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct3d10) are mapped accordingly. On the other hand, it seems that [directx12](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/directx12) is a *synonym* for [direct3d12](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/direct3d12), which is the *target* tag instead:

[image]

I'm currently not sure if this occurred with other tags as well. Shall this be fixed, or isn't it worth the effort?

Comment: I think knowing this will annoy a bunch of users from now on if we don't do something about it :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated the tag synonyms.

[image]